# iPhone - block enumeration

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks

I have an array with several objects and I want to add 90.0 to each value. **I want to do this using enumerate.** Then I create this:

```
[myArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent
     usingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

     double aValue = [obj doubleValue];                      
     aValue += 90.0;
     obj = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:aValue];
}];
```

my question is regarding the last line. I get the object value, add 90 and then I have to store it back. As this is a little bit weird, because I am working on the object level, I was not sure if the third line has the correct syntax to store the updated value back on the object. Xcode complains "obj" is never used, because it thinks I am assigning the number to obj with the intention to use it, but I am just storing the value back.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way would be to store the amended values to a new array:

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[myArray count]];
__block newArray;
[myArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent usingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

 double aValue = [obj doubleValue];                      
 aValue += 90.0;
 [newArray insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:aValue] atIndex:idx];
}];
```

*note* I've typed this straight in, so please excuse any syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

`obj` is not a reference or a pointer, you can't actually store it back. `NSArray` does not support this functionality. What you can do is instead of storing NSNumbers, store pointers to NSNumber (that is NSNumber**) and update the reference to a new object.

Storing your numbers in normal `double[]` array would work also.

Comment: You can only enumerate on objects. double is not an object. NSNumber is.

Comment: I did not mean he'd be able to enumerate on them via a regular enumerate* message, I just meant it'd be easier to update each element when it's in an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do an in-place operation, you can use this:

```
[myArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent usingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) 
{
    double aValue = [obj doubleValue];                      
    aValue += 90.0;
    [myArray replaceObjectAtIndex:idx withObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:aValue]];
}];
```

Although NSMutableArray is not supposed to be threadsafe, that is usually only if you are changing the size of it. Worked fine in a simple test, but use at your own risk.

Comment: I did that before, but I received an error saying I cannot change an array that is being enumerated... :(